# JS Countdown Timer Website Won't Reset Automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Made this webpage a few months ago (timenite.com/item-shop) and it basically is a Countdown that should just show a 24 Hour Timer every day until 00:00 UTC, the problem with this is that every day, I have to change the date in the script which is kind of frustrating.

Could something be implemented to this code so that every time the timer hits 0, it resets back to 24:00:00 back to itself?

Below is the code in the .js file, there were two files actually but I combined them just in case.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            date: null,
            offset: null,
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days',
            hour: 'Hour',
            hours: 'Hours',
            minute: 'Minute',
            minutes: 'Minutes',
            second: 'Second',
            seconds: 'Seconds'
        }, options);

        // Throw error if date is not set
        if (!settings.date) {
            $.error('Date is not defined.');
        }

        // Throw error if date is set incorectly
        if (!Date.parse(settings.date)) {
            $.error('Incorrect date format, it should look like this, 12/24/2012 12:00:00.');
        }

        // Save container
        var container = this;

        /**
         * Change client's local date to match offset timezone
         * @return {Object} Fixed Date object.
         */
        var currentDate = function () {
            // get client's current date
            var date = new Date();

            // turn date to utc
            var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

            // set new Date object
            var new_date = new Date(utc + (3600000*settings.offset));

            return new_date;
        };

        /**
         * Main countdown function that calculates everything
         */
        function countdown () {
            var target_date = new Date(settings.date), // set target date
                current_date = currentDate(); // get fixed current date

            // difference of dates
            var difference = target_date - current_date;

            // if difference is negative than it's pass the target date
            if (difference < 0) {
                // stop timer
                clearInterval(interval);

                if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();

                return;
            }

            // basic math variables
            var _second = 1000,
                _minute = _second * 60,
                _hour = _minute * 60,
                _day = _hour * 24;

            // calculate dates
            var days = Math.floor(difference / _day),
                hours = Math.floor((difference % _day) / _hour),
                minutes = Math.floor((difference % _hour) / _minute),
                seconds = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _second);

            // based on the date change the refrence wording
            var text_days = (days === 1) ? settings.day : settings.days,
                text_hours = (hours === 1) ? settings.hour : settings.hours,
                text_minutes = (minutes === 1) ? settings.minute : settings.minutes,
                text_seconds = (seconds === 1) ? settings.second : settings.seconds;

                // fix dates so that it will show two digets
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : '0' + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : '0' + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : '0' + seconds;

            // set to DOM
            container.find('.days').text(days);
            container.find('.hours').text(hours);
            container.find('.minutes').text(minutes);
            container.find('.seconds').text(seconds);

            container.find('.days_text').text(text_days);
            container.find('.hours_text').text(text_hours);
            container.find('.minutes_text').text(text_minutes);
            container.find('.seconds_text').text(text_seconds);
        }

        // start
        var interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    };

})(jQuery);

$(".openNav").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("navOpen");
  $("nav").toggleClass("open");
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("open");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});


// Second File from here

var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDate();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var year = now.getFullYear() + 1;

var nextyear = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' 07:07:07';

$('#example').countdown({
    date: '02/24/20 0:00:00', // TODO Date format: 07/27/2017 17:00:00
    // offset: +3, // TODO Your Timezone Offset
    day: 'Day',
    days: 'Days'
}, function () {
    day++;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change second file a bit:

```js
var today = new Date()
var tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)
var day = tomorrow.getDate();
var month = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
var year = tomorrow.getFullYear();

var nextday = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' 00:00:00';

$('#example').countdown({
    date: nextday,
    day: 'Day',
    days: 'Days'
}, function () {
    day++;
});
```